sp_executesql In Loop Taking FOREVER to Run. Slowing down as it runs. Memory Leak?
Long and short is that my query is taking FOREVER to run and I think it has to do with the sp_executesql queries.  Yes, there are loops, and yes I am using Dynamic SQL.
I use loops enough to know there is something going on, this is taking far longer than it should to run.  The only thing I can think is that the sp_executesql is not well formed or something.
The [tmp_compare] table will have about 8500 records, and there are 15 fields it compares, so I know that's 127,000 "processes", but it should not take HOURS to run, right?!
I tracked it running for 90min and it starts running at 84 records (entries into data_log) per second. After an hour it's down to 14 records/second.  It gradually slows down as it goes.  Last time I saw something like this was when a program I wrote had a memory leak.  I fixed the previous issue I had with the data types, and it did speed it up a bit, but something still seems wrong.  Do I need to clear variables or something?  What am I missing here?
Purpose:
I am comparing specific columns from two tables and putting the data and proposed action based on the data into another table to act upon later.  The [contact_compare_fields] table holds the field names for the two tables, and the [tmp_compare] is just a list of the IDs
Table Creation/Prep:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contact_compare_fields] 
(
    [id]       int identity(1,1),
    [sf_field] varchar(100),
    [h_field]  varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO [contact_compare_fields] 
VALUES
    ('Title',               'Job Title'),
    ('FirstName',           'First Name'),
    ('LastName',            'Last Name'),
    ('MailingStreet',       'Person Street'),
    ('MailingCity',         'Person City'),
    ('MailingState',        'Person State'),
    ('MailingPostalCode',   'Person Zip Code'),
    ('MailingCountry',      'Country'),
    ('Department',          'Department'),
    ('Email',               'Email Address'),
    ('Phone',               'Direct Phone Number'),
    ('Fax',                 'Fax'),
    ('MobilePhone',         'Mobile Phone'),
    ('Job_Level__c',        'Management Level'),
    ('Job_Role__c',         'Job Function')
    
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_compare] 
(
    [id]      int identity(1,1),
    [H_ZI_ID] bigint
)

INSERT INTO [tmp_compare] 
VALUES
    ('1001122877'),('1001125385'),('1002260105'),('100233801'),('1002661679')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[h_processed] 
(
    [Contact ID] varchar(255),
    [Job Title]  varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO [h_processed] 
VALUES ('1001122877', 'Chief Financial Officer')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sf_contact] 
(
    [Contact ID] varchar(255),
    [Title]  varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO [sf_contact] 
VALUES ('1001122877', 'CFO')

CREATE TABLE [data_log] (
    [id]        int identity(1,1),
    [dataID]    varchar(500),
    [field]     varchar(128),
    [sf_data]   varchar(500),
    [h_data]    varchar(500),
    [score]     float,
    [action]    varchar(128)
);

CODE:
DECLARE
    @fld_cnt int = 1,
    @fld_max int = 0,
    @cnt int = 1,
    @max int = 0,
    @score float,
    @zi bigint,
    @value int = 0,
    @sf_field nvarchar(500) = '',
    @h_field nvarchar(500) = '',
    @sf_data nvarchar(500) = '',
    @h_data nvarchar(500) = '',
    @ParamDef nvarchar(500) = '',
    @sql nvarchar(max)
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [tmp_compare];
SELECT
    identity(int,1,1) AS [id],
    h.[Contact ID] AS [H_ZI_ID]
 INTO [tmp_compare]
 FROM [h_processed] h
  LEFT JOIN [sf_contact] s ON
    h.[Contact ID] =  s.[DOZISF__ZnID__c]
  WHERE s.[DOZISF__ZI_ID__c] IS NOT NULL 
    AND s.[DOZISF__ZI_ID__c] <> ''

SELECT @fld_max = COUNT(*) FROM [contact_compare_fields]
SELECT @max = COUNT(*) FROM [tmp_compare]


-- Cycle Through Every ID in [tmp_compare] table
WHILE (@cnt <= @max)
BEGIN
    SELECT @zi = [H_ZI_ID] FROM [tmp_compare] WHERE [id] = @cnt

    -- Cycle Through Every Field in the Table
    WHILE (@fld_cnt <= @fld_max)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sf_field = [sf_field], @h_field = [h_field] FROM [contact_compare_fields] WHERE [id] = @fld_cnt
        
        SET @sql = N'SELECT @h_dataOUT = SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank(' + QUOTENAME(@h_field) + ') FROM [h_processed] WHERE [Contact ID] = @ziIN;';
        SET @ParamDef = N'@ziIN bigint, @h_dataOUT varchar(500) OUTPUT';
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParamDef, @ziIN = @zi, @h_dataOUT = @h_data OUTPUT;

        SET @sql = N'SELECT @sf_dataOUT  = SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank(' + QUOTENAME(@sf_field) + ') FROM [sf_contact] WHERE [DOZISF__ZI_ID__C] = @ziIN;';
        SET @ParamDef = N'@ziIN bigint, @sf_dataOUT varchar(500) OUTPUT';
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParamDef, @ziIN = @zi, @sf_dataOUT = @sf_data OUTPUT;

        INSERT INTO [data_log] VALUES
            (@zi, @sf_field, @sf_data, @h_data, NULL, '')

        IF (@sf_data = @h_data)
            UPDATE [data_log] SET [action] = 'None' WHERE [DataID] = @zi AND [field] = @sf_field;
        ELSE IF (@sf_data IS NULL) AND (@h_data IS NULL)
            UPDATE [data_log] SET [action] = 'None' WHERE [DataID] = @zi AND [field] = @sf_field;
        ELSE IF (@sf_data IS NOT NULL) AND (@h_data IS NULL)
            UPDATE [data_log] SET [action] = 'None' WHERE [DataID] = @zi AND [field] = @sf_field;
        ELSE IF (@sf_data IS NULL) AND (@h_data IS NOT NULL)
            UPDATE [data_log] SET [action] = 'UPDATE' WHERE [DataID] = @zi AND [field] = @sf_field;
        ELSE
            UPDATE [data_log] SET [action] = 'Needs Review' WHERE [DataID] = @zi AND [field] = @sf_field;

        SET @fld_cnt = @fld_cnt + 1
    END

    SET @fld_cnt = 1
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END


In a loop there's your problem. That's the absolute slowest way to do anything in SQL. SQL is a set-based language. 127K rows is a small amount of data. Explain what you want to do so people can help you do it properly.

Yes, there are loops, and yes I am using Dynamic SQL. No, I do not really understand CTEs and can never get them to work, you don't need CTEs to use the results of one query in another. You won't be able to do anything in SQL until you understand how to use subqueries and JOINs. Falling back to loops never works. UPDATE target SET  ... FROM source INNER JOIN target ON target.SomeColumn=source.SomeColumn WHERE ... can update a target table with data from the source table

You really have to start from the start and explain the actual problem (business case, tables with meaningful names, logic, sample data) because the current code is very hard to read. It will take far too long to reverse engineer the actual tables and columns from this. The only reason I can make some sense of it is that I'm already working on data validation but I don't use dynamic fields, nor do I try to run rules row by row

@PanagiotisKanavos I added the "purpose".  I included tables and some sample data for everything already, so there shouldn't be any reverse engineering.  I don't think what I am trying to do is difficult, and I THOUGHT it would be better/easier to do it with dynamic sql than write queries for each and every field individually.

It's not. As for what you try to do it's named Row-By-Agonizing-Row

I can't update the tables like that.  I need to have them separately to be reviewed.  Maybe the data_log can be created better without the score or action, then run queries to update those afterwards.

I'm working with multiple 30M row tables and complex rules right now. Yes, you can update the tables. First though, you need to explain what you want to do. That purpose sentence is unclear to everyone else. There are no tables, no columns, no business rules or logic. The [contact_compare_fields] table holds the field names for the two tables that's a critical bug. Instead of making your system "dynamic" that makes it very hard to maintain and optimize

First of all, 120K rows is small enough you can just load the data in eg a Pandas dataframe and apply rules there - without looping. If you know Python, this may be a viable solution. There are libraries like Pydantic or Pandera that allow you to specify checks and rules to entire dataframes and find violations

You need to do some analysis and determine whether its specific tables that are taking longer to run Vs the order they are run in. And check the execution plans for the queries to determine what and where the slow down is. Or maybe you've consumed all the servers RAM and it's having to swap it out

Another option is to create a view with a calculated field for each rule and filter it by "failing" fields. You can use that view to update the failing rows or insert failures into another table.

@DaleK this is a row-by-row nested loop, with one iteration per field, not just row. Even if the fields were indexed it would still be the slowest possible solution. This code executes 15*127K queries

Trying adding some indexes to your temp tables. The loop is of course bad, but if you don't have so many rows, it shouldn't be that bad. Unless you also don't have any indexes on h_processed etc. Also what in the name of god is SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank, don't use scalar functions if you want decent performance, especially for trivial tasks

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, you got me thinking about it differently and I think I have a plan.

In my case, to compare financial transactions from two different systems,  I joined transaction tables on the common key and then calculated one flag for every rule. Those were stored in the comparison table. This way it was very easy and quick to calculate specific failure cases and generate reports. You can make the comparison fast if you only calculate the rules for changed rows. Instead of working on all 127K rows every day, you could work on only the 1000 new rows every hour. Using Columnstore indexes works very well for such cases

@PanagiotisKanavos I would appreciate your insight on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78635017/how-to-limit-inner-join-to-single-row-for-update

This doesn't need loops at all. You just need to dynamically construct a joined query that unpivots the columns, and compares them, inserting into the log as necessary.
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(N'
      (' + QUOTENAME(ccf.sf_field, '''') + ', sf.' + QUOTENAME(ccf.sf_field) + ', hp.' + QUOTENAME(ccf.h_field) + ')',
    N','
  )
FROM contact_compare_fields ccf;

SET @sql = '
INSERT data_log (dataID, field, sf_data, h_data, action)
SELECT
  sf.[Contact ID],
  v.column_name,
  v.sf_data,
  v.h_data,
  CASE WHEN v.sf_data = v.h_data OR v.h_data IS NULL THEN ''None''
       WHEN v.sf_data IS NULL AND v.h_data IS NOT NULL THEN ''UPDATE''
       ELSE ''Needs Review''
  END
FROM tmp_compare tc
JOIN sf_contact sf ON sf.[Contact ID] = CAST(tc.[H_ZI_ID] AS varchar(255))
JOIN h_processed hp ON hp.[Contact ID] = sf.[Contact ID]
CROSS APPLY (VALUES' + @cols + '
) v(column_name, sf_data, h_data);
';

PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM data_log

db<>fiddle
Note:

Make sure you always quote column names with QUOTENAME.
Column and object names should be stored in sysname typed columns and variables.
If the column types differ then you should cast them all to them same type, either a string type or sql_variant.
In your sample, tc.[H_ZI_ID] and [Contact ID] have different data types. These should be the same type.
The tables should all have clustered indexes on [Contact ID] and [H_ZI_ID] respectively.


That is great, I'm going to copy that and see if I can understand it enough to reuse it.  What I came up with is VERY similar.  It still has a loop, but only loops through the 15 sets of fields, and then I build a dynamic query to load the data_log directly.  It cut out a LOT records I didn't need this way :)

I would appreciate your insight on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78635017/how-to-limit-inner-join-to-single-row-for-update

Still doesn't sound like you need a loop, but whatever.
