How to limit INNER JOIN to single Row for Update
I am attempting to optimize some very ugly queries.  I have this query here that is grabbing the abbreviation for a state since we are only working with abbreviations.
UPDATE [data_log] 
   SET [h_data] = COALESCE((SELECT TOP(1) [state_abbr] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [state_long] = [h_data]), [h_data])
 WHERE [field] = 'MailingState'
   AND LEN([h_data]) > 3
   AND [h_data] IS NOT NULL

The data log is just a table where I am tracking changes that need to be made, or need to  be reviewed.
CREATE TABLE [data_log] (
    [id]        int identity(1,1),
    [dataID]    bigint,
    [field]     varchar(128),
    [sf_data]   varchar(500),
    [h_data]    varchar(500),
    [score]     float,
    [action]    varchar(128)
);

INSERT INTO [Data_log] VALUES 
(3605013844, '[MailingCity]', 'Flat', 'Flatt', NULL, NULL),
(3605013844, '[MailingState]', 'KY', 'Kentucky', NULL, NULL),
(3605013844, '[MailingZIP]', '41301', '41301', NULL, NULL),
(1874281127, '[MailingCity]', 'EDMONTON', 'Edmonton', NULL, NULL),
(1874281127, '[MailingState]', 'AB', 'Alberta', NULL, NULL),
(1874281127, '[MailingZIP]', 'T6M 2K1', 'T6M 2K1', NULL, NULL),
(2077170855, '[MailingCity]', 'Van Buren Point', 'Van Buren Point', NULL, NULL),
(2077170855, '[MailingState]', 'NY', 'New York', NULL, NULL),
(2077170855, '[MailingZIP]', '14166', '14166', NULL, NULL),
(1874281127, '[MailingState]', 'PA', 'Ontario', NULL, NULL),
(1874281127, '[MailingState]', 'IL', 'Missouri', NULL, NULL)

The [CityStateInfo] has a ton of info for the US, Canada, Mexico and Europe.  It has 3,764,649 rows.  It has every City/State/Zip combo for everywhere, along with other info.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CityStateInfo](
    [City] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [State_abbr] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [State_long] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Longitude] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Latitude] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [StateFIPS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CountryFIPS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TimeZone] [int] NULL,
    [cleanCity] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Country_abbr] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [foreignCity] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [foreignState] [varchar](255) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [CityStateInfo] VALUES
('AARON','KY','Kentucky','42602','RUSSELL','United States','-85.121708','36.751734','21','207','6','AARON','US',NULL,NULL),
('AARON','KY','Kentucky','42602','CLINTON','United States','-85.121708','36.751734','21','053','6','AARON','US',NULL,NULL),
('ADRIAN','MO','Missouri','64720','BATES','United States','-94.398772','38.433513','29','013','6','ADRIAN','US',NULL,NULL),
('ADVANCE','MO','Missouri','63730','CAPE GIRARDEAU','United States','-89.911055','37.058424','29','031','6','ADVANCE','US',NULL,NULL),
('SHIRLEY','NY','New York','11967','SUFFOLK','United States','-72.880184','40.794219','36','103','5','SHIRLEY','US',NULL,NULL),
('SHOKAN','NY','New York','12481','ULSTER','United States','-74.214799','41.982148','36','111','5','SHOKAN','US',NULL,NULL),
('KANATA','ON','Ontario','K2M 0A8',NULL,'Canada',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'5','KANATA','CA',NULL,NULL),
('KANATA','ON','Ontario','K2M 0A9',NULL,'Canada',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'5','KANATA','CA',NULL,NULL),
('EDMONTON','AB','Alberta','T6H 0J5',NULL,'Canada',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'7','EDMONTON','CA',NULL,NULL),
('EDMONTON','AB','Alberta','T6H 0J6',NULL,'Canada',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'7','EDMONTON','CA',NULL,NULL)

I thought I could do something like this
    UPDATE [data_log]
       SET [data_log].[h_data] = c.[state_abbr]
      FROM [data_log] d
INNER JOIN [CityStateInfo] c
        ON d.[h_data] = c.[state_long]
     WHERE d.[field] = '[MailingState]'
       AND LEN([h_data]) > 3
       AND [h_data] IS NOT NULL

But, when I do a select with a similar setup I get millions of lines since each State that I am looking for can have dozens or even thousands of rows.  While the query above does seem to get me what I want, I want to ensure I am not calling up millions of rows just to edit a couple dozen, which would defeat the purpose of trying to clean up the query.
    SELECT * FROM [data_log] d
INNER JOIN [CityStateInfo] c
        ON d.[h_data] = c.[state_long]
     WHERE d.[field] = '[MailingState]'
       AND LEN([h_data]) > 3
       AND [h_data] IS NOT NULL

So, how can I alter the UPDATE query so that it's just matching with a single row for the edit and not spinning through way more cycles than needed?
SQL Fiddle

I don't see an actual problem statement here.  Can you please show clear sample input data along with the output you want?

Are you trying to ask how to update the most recent row?

@TimBiegeleisen The query works, and I put it in the SQL FIddle so you can see it works, and I get the output I want.  I am just not sure if it's trying to process millions of rows to update that ONE record or not.  I've never tried an update from a table like the [CityStateInfo[ table before.

No it's not necessarily processing all the rows, it's just picking one arbitrary one. It may need to aggregate the whole table, or it may to a nested loop style. But it will be non-deterministic: you may get a different result each time, or a result you don't expect. What result do you want, how do you want it to deal with multiple matches? Note that TOP (1) without an ORDER BY is also non-deterministic.

Does this answer your question? How to Join to first row

AND [h_data] IS NOT NULL is superfluous. It's already covered by LEN([h_data]) > 3.

There are two sections that could be optimized in the UPDATE: 1) The filtering [field] = 'MailingState' AND LEN([h_data]) > 3 and 2) the correlated subquery. The latter is easy to optimize with a simple index. The former could be optimized if the selected rows represent a small subset of rows (less than 0.5%); what percentaje of rows are updated (in average)?

(Reposted comment with correction): As mentioned in the above-linked answer, the general solution is to use a CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 columns_or_* FROM JoinedTable WHERE condition ORDER BY something) A. Usually, the ORDER BY is important to select which matching row would be selected, but in your case, order is "don't care" and the order-by clause can be omitted.

Since you need only state_long and state_abbr from CityStateInfo:
    SELECT *
      FROM [data_log] d
INNER JOIN (
           select distinct csi.state_long
           , csi.state_abbr
           from [CityStateInfo] csi
           ) c
        ON d.[h_data] = c.[state_long]
     WHERE d.[field] = '[MailingState]'
       AND LEN([h_data]) > 3

...produces smaller output, so...
    UPDATE [data_log]
       SET [data_log].[h_data] = c.[state_abbr]
      FROM [data_log] d
INNER JOIN (
           select distinct csi.state_long
           , csi.state_abbr
           from [CityStateInfo] csi
           ) c
        ON d.[h_data] = c.[state_long]
     WHERE d.[field] = '[MailingState]'
       AND LEN([h_data]) > 3

...would involve less data.  But it also involves an additional processing step.  You should check performance both ways to determine what will work best in your environment.
